# Как воспользоваться элементами Редактора ленты (Ribbon) в Панели элементов, проект WPF

Tags: wpf, ribbon

Как воспользоваться элементами из <Редактора ленты (Ribbon)> в <Панели элементов>, проект WPF?
Элементы из этой панели не переносятся на Ribbon((
[image: Пояснение]

Comment: Забудьте про эту панель раз и на всегда, забудьте вообще про дизайнер, как элемент **создания UI**, используйте его **лишь для визуализации** того, что вы написали сами, руками, в XAML разметке! Спросите почему? Все просто: он "глупый", очень и делает кучу лишнего в коде, что потом приводит к разным проблемам. Так что смотрите документацию и вызывайте самый нужный контрол в XAML разметке (`<ns:SomeControl/>`).

Comment: Спасибо, понял)
Но если панель есть, она ведь как-то должна активироваться?